# Call a server side MVC action on the click of a Kendo UI button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I just download a trial version of v2013.3.1119.440 of the Kendo UI wrappers for ASP.NET MVC. I see a new `Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ButtonBuilder` wrapper in this version that wasn't in the version I had downloaded just 20 days ago on another PC.

The said wrapper represents a button.

I can't see a way to directly wire this `Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ButtonBuilder` wrapper with a server side MVC action. How do I do that?

I do see the `Events` method on the `ButtonBuilder` class, which accepts a `Action<ButtonEventBuilder>` events. In the `ButtonEventBuilder`, I see another method called `Click`, which has two overloads, but both are for wiring client side event handlers of the button.

I don't see a way to directly wire up a server side call-back/post-back with the button click.

Am I missing something? Is the only way to do it the manual way of firing the server side post back or call back from a JavaScript function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Button` is new in the latest release of Kendo UI (last week).  It doesn't directly support what you're looking for, but something similar could be accomplished like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("textButton")
    .Content("Text button")
    .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
    .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick")))
```

Then a JS function similar to this:

```
function onClick(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action'
        data: { // data here }
    }).done(function(result){
        // do something with the result
    }).fail(function() { // handle failure });
}
```

More info can be found in their demo site: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/button/events.html

Comment: Thanks. That was what I suspected. 6 more minutes before I can mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: At that point, it may be easier to just use an `<a href="#" class="k-button"></a>` and do it that way.